# CSS Button Tweaks

Tags: button, css, cross-browser, styles

I have built a custom `<button>`, which is styled completely using CSS and CSS3. Everything works very well, with the exception of a few visual annoyances that vary across browsers.

I notice in Internet Explorer and Firefox after my button is pressed, a dotted border is visible around the text of the button, like this:

[image]

This is not the case with Chrome or Opera.

Also, during the button click in Internet Explorer and Opera, the text of the button moves to indicate that the user clicked the button:

[image]

This is not an issue within Chrome or Firefox.

Is there a way within CSS to remove the dotted border and shifting text within the above mentioned browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show current CSS on the buttons? I think something like this would fix the issue for you in Internet Explorer not sure of FireFox...

```
a.button:active, a.button:selected, a.button:visited { 
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: yes that fixed the `outline` property fixed the dotted border issue within IE, but not Firefox. I am actually using a border withing my button, so I didn't apply the first suggestion. Thank you Ryan!

Comment: In Firefox, after you click on something, if you don't go to a new page or something, your focus is still sitting on that button. Yet, you want :focus styles. You could instead have a whole style for :focus that doesn't include the outline. That way, keyboarders get love and while the :focus style will remain in FF (and some other browsers), it won't be the fugly outline.